# 20.04 problem after update applied

Tags: boot, 20.04, updates, crash

I have been running Ubuntu on my laptop for some years. Currently running 20.04 and have been since its release. The system is updated regularly or when prompted using sudo apt update..Ran such an update a few days ago - computer ran OK.

On next reboot - the following evening - boot hung at blank screen. Had to perform hard shutdown. On restart, recovery mode was offered and chosen. Computer booted OK.

Next reboot - same problem. Blank screen and frozen boot. Hard shutdown and recovery worked OK. Tried to find any evidence of problem but with my limited knowledge, no luck.  Decided that as there was little on the computer I would do a fresh install of 20.04 from USB flash drive.  All went well, computer booted OK and was usable.  After successful boot, message appeared saying updated software was available - did I want to install - chose yes. XXX Mb to be downloaded.

Software downloaded and started to install then screen came up - problem detected, unable to recover - log out.  Could only do hard reset. On reboot - back to blank screen and frozen boot process.

Seems obvious to me that the latest software updates are causing the problem but how do I find out what element of the update is the cause?  At the actual point of crash, everything happens so fast it is impossible to see what element is running in the details window.

I have been around Ubuntu for a few years but cannot claim to be well versed in diagnostics so if someone can help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: It maybe a kernel upgrade (updated 5.4 kernel patch that your system doesn't like), where I'd normally hit a key so grub is visible & an older kernel is selected to see if the issue is gone. I'd then explore launchpad (Ubuntu's bug tracker) to see if others experienced the issue, and hopefully would learn more there... By re-installing you've likely got fewer older (particularly recent) kernels to choose from, maybe what was on the install media only.//   I'd also likely scan logs, and boot without `quiet splash` so more messages are on display..  Hard shutdown means?  (a SysRq shutdown?)

Comment: By Hard Shutdown I men pressing and holding the power key until computer shuts down. This is the only way I can close down as computer does not respond to keyboard.

Comment: Even if the GUI is locked up, as long as the kernel is still running (ie. no kernel panic messages are on the screen), you can use SysRq keys to directly command the kernel to safely shutdown the system  (if you forget the keys/commands, a quick search on a phone or other device for "magic sysrq" will display the wikipedia page which is a pretty good guide)...  If the SysRq keys are not responding, that in itself is a HUGE clue as it means the kernel is dead (cannot respond), thus that detail itself is useful in diagnostic terms (if kernel is running system is good, GUI/display only has died)